# AWS Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook Stopped Printing

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Jupyter Notebook instance through AWS Sagemaker. My script runs two models, performing up to 48 jobs at once (this shouldn't be an issue for the instance size I selected). There are also lines on the script that print a short description of where it's at:

```
...    
print("Loading training data")
...
print("Training model: Random Forest")
...
print("Training model: K-Nearest Neighbors")
...
(etc.)
```

At one point, the number of tasks the instance was working declined and were eventually replaced with tasks that all began running around the same time, and have been running every since. I assume this means the random forest model has completed training, and the KNN one initiated training. However, it appears as though the notebook has stopped printing results.

My question is, what am I experiencing? Did I do something that ceased the script printing? Will the script continue to run after the second model is done training, or will the script crash?

Comment: I have the same problem. With my case, I don't think it's due to a shortage of RAM, nor is it a result of the notebook session expiring. It just stops printing results after running for several hours.